# How to add python-module to openwrt custom build?

Tags: linux, compilation, router, openwrt

Is there a way add python modules to openwrt at build time?
I have read bits and pieces on how to use menueconfig to add packages but I'm unsure if that's only used for specific software or if it can be used to include any package type.